# Is using one function inside styled less performant?

Tags: emotion

```
const Container = styled.div<{ column: string }>(
  (props) => css`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: ${props.column};
  `
);
```

versus

```
const Container = styled.div<{ column: "red"; }>`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: ${p => p.column};
`;
```

Though the first approach scales better if there are multiple prop-dependent properties (the whole function does not need to be specified every time), all examples use the second approach.

What is the reasoning behind it? Is the first approach less performant?